# docker-compose: rename on dead container (using Datadog)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, datadog

Using docker-compose for a small application sending to a Datadog container, I have a problem when trying to register StatsD against the Datadog container (DD agent logs):

```
datadog  | 2023-06-13 17:23:21 UTC | PROCESS | WARN | (pkg/workloadmeta/collectors/internal/docker/docker.go:108 in stream) | received event: rename on dead container: "76703f8ade55c49a2c14107e123e3bd286cfa23ef635522b6fcc92211ed0ebdf", discarding
```

However, this setup (and the code used within the app) works when using it on AWS as an ECS Task Definition.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    networks: [local_network]
    build: .
    env_file: .env
    command: "npm run start:app"

  datadog:
    container_name: datadog
    networks: [local_network]
    image: datadog/agent
    env_file: .datadog.env
    ports:
      - '8126:8126/tcp'
      - '18125:8125/udp'
    volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
     - /proc/:/host/proc/:ro
     - /sys/fs/cgroup:/host/sys/fs/cgroup:ro


networks:
  local_network:
```

The env files for each:

**.env:**

```
DATADOG_ENV=staging
DATADOG_HOST=datadog
DATADOG_PORT=8125
```

**.datadog.env:**

```
DD_SITE=datadoghq.com
DD_APM_ENABLED=true
DD_APM_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC=true
DD_DOGSTATSD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC=true
DD_API_KEY=xxx
DD_HOSTNAME=datadog
DD_DOGSTATSD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC=true
```

I have the feeling it's a network issue between the container, i.e. that it is a docker-compose issue (not a Datadog specific issue: the Datadog container itself is able to send metrics to the main site) but cannot find the issue itself.

Tried with separate simple py and ts applications, and same outcome, so it's not application dependent.

Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc
Docker Compose version v2.5.0